# Is the junction box necessary with flush-mount LED fixture?

Tags: wiring, led

Awesome and quick responses on my wiring question yesterday, and I appreciate it. I am replacing these fixtures with [LED Wraparound light fixtures](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-4-ft-High-Output-5200-Lumens-Integrated-LED-White-Wraparound-Light-4000K-Bright-White-120-277V-Energy-Star-Rated-54677691/313258651), but, as the ceilings are unfinished, the junction boxes protrude to the point where fixing the wraparounds to them is a little tricky.

Are the junction boxes necessary being that the connections will now be inside of the wraparound?

[image]

Comment: What is a "wraparound"?

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-4-ft-High-Output-5200-Lumens-Integrated-LED-White-Wraparound-Light-4000K-Bright-White-120-277V-Energy-Star-Rated-54677691/313258651

Comment: You can probably carefully pry the box off and nail it back a 1/2" higher.

Answer (score 3):

The instructions that are included with the light say to install with a junction box.
[image]

The fixture doesn't have a knockout hole that a NB cable connector  can attach to to make the connections inside the fixture. Since the existing junction box is lower than the joists, you can shim the joists to match the offset or just raise the junction box to the level of the joist.

Comment: I saw that, and what does not make sense is that the wires from the fixture are way too short to connect in a box. As is they would have to be connected inside of the fixture, no matter the configuration.

Comment: @Adman  Check inside the fixture and see if you can route the cable through another hole to give you more slack to make the connections.  Make sure there's no slack inside the fixture.

Comment: There's no slack at all, and there is only one center punch out in the fixture. The only other holes are the keyholes for mounting.

Comment: If push comes to shove, add some extra  14 AWG  wire and splice to the fixture wire. All connectors will still have to be in the junction box.

Comment: @Adman some lights from Big Orange are an insane pain to install. I had to install recently a flat LED fixture in my closet and it was absolutely awful. After a lot of grunting and holding my arms above my head for way too long, I managed it. Only later did I look at the online reviews and find that everyone who bought the light complained about installation. Point is — look for a light that is specifically easy to install or be prepared to struggle with wires that are too short.

Comment: @RibaldEddie  The instructions even say it's a two man job.   Some of them are really ridiculous to install.

Comment: JACK, the installation would be more similar to this video where the technician brings the wire down, makes the connections inside the fixture, and then seals the fixture. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnsBlic6E9Y

Comment: I have learned, the hard way, that Commercial Electric is a Big Orange house brand of the "cheap as possible" variety. After dealing with some returns (which Big Orange is *very* good at handling, to their credit), I moved up to Lithonia (using the credit at Home Depot - problem isn't the store, it is the particular brand/product). Much better quality. Looking at the diagram in a similar Lithonia light, they have it set up (typically, may vary by model) so you can legitimately do splices in the light fixture. As far as this particular fixture though, instructions (see "2") show 3 knockouts.

Comment: I wouldn't move the existing junction box. I would *replace it* with a metal box and mount that so the light will be flush with the joists.

Comment: @Adman  That would b easier if your fixture had the larger hole and the cable grip. Which it doesn't appear to have.  Codes require following the directions.

Comment: The similar Lithonia lights have the same exact configuration. They come with short wires and connectors. The video I included is Lithonia, and the technician makes the connections and stores them in the wraparound, not the box. I just looked, and our lights at work are all the same way. WTF, lol.

Comment: The difference is that the Lithonia (or at least the one I looked at) have an internal metal cover over a wiring section - effectively the same as putting the wires in a metal junction box and designed for that purpose. It is the kind of 50-cent extra piece of a design that makes a difference but which gets left out of the cheaper stuff because "use the junction box and include a little bit longer wires" is ever so slightly cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

A junction box of some kind is necessary anywhere separate wires are connected to each other in a non-permanent fashion. The j-box has to be accessible or “readily” accessible. So yes, you’ll need some kind of junction box there.

If the existing junction box for some reason sticks out past the joist at a depth greater than the finish ceiling material (usually 1/2” drywall) then yes you might want to replace or adjust it to be flush with the bottom of the joist.

There is the possibility that you could use the fixture’s wiring area as a junction box itself, but only if is marked with a volume for that purpose. I would suggest you keep the junction box because it would allow you change the light fixture in the future without undoing the wires to downstream fixtures or outlets.

Comment: This is in a garage with an unfinished ceiling. I attempted to relocate the old junction box, but it is just way too "tall" meaning that it still leaves too much gap between the fixture and the joist I need to secure it to.

Comment: @Adman ceiling mount junction boxes come in different depth sizes and shapes. You can find one with less depth at most hardware stores or electrical supply stores. Just get a smaller one that will fit. You do need to be cognizant of box fill rules but since you only have two 14/2 cables coming into the box, practically any ceiling box will work. Even a pancake box.

Comment: I'm thinking I may just do that. It would be easier in the long run.

Comment: Replace it. With a *metal* box.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the titular question: "Yes" (as noted in the other answers) a junction box is *always* required to contain wire junctions.

To resolve the issue of the existing box sticking down below the unfinished ceiling height making it difficult to install the light and/or funny looking because it's not touching the joists elsewhere:

Install some 1/2" blocking on the other joists that the new fixture crosses. Attach the fixture to the blocking by running screws through the fixture and into the blocking, thus securely attaching the new fixture to the joists.

This blocking could be pieces of 1/2" plywood or drywall, or pieces of 2x dimensional lumber cut into 1/2" thick slices. Note that if you do use dimensional lumber, you will need to drill pilot holes both for attaching the blocking to the joists and for attaching the light to the blocking since the screws will be going into end grain of a fairly thin piece of wood and will have a *high* likelihood of splitting it if you don't pre-drill.